# Factorial using recursive functions. Traced the code but cannot figure out why the error is coming

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

```
def factorial_recursive(n):
    while n > 1:
        factorial = factorial * n
        factorial_recursive(n - 1)
    return factorial
num = input("Please enter the number whose factorial you want to find ")
num = int(num)
factorial = 1
if num == 0:
    print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num < 0:
    print("The factorial of a negative number cannot be computed")
elif num == 1:
    print("The factorial of 1 is 1")
else:
    print("The factorial is", factorial_recursive(num))
```

Error message:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-c3621871e051> in <module>()
     16 else:
     17     factorial = 1
---> 18     print("The factorial is", factorial_recursive(num))

<ipython-input-28-c3621871e051> in factorial_recursive(n)
      2 def factorial_recursive(n):
      3     while n > 1:
----> 4         factorial = factorial * n
      5         factorial_recursive(n - 1)
      6     return factorial

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'factorial' referenced before assignment
```

I have seen the working code of using recursive functions to find the factorial of a number. I was trying to do it on my own and I have traced the code at each step but can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: the question has nothing to do with factorial or recurrent functions. Its about `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'factorial' referenced before assignment` which happens when you use undeclared variable. There's a question about that already, so I recommend closing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `factorial = factorial * n` refers to a local variable named `factorial` - which you have never created. So you're using an unbound variable.

It seems you are trying to refer to the `factorial` in the global scope, outside the function. In that case, you need to declare that using the `global` keyword

```py
def factorial_recursive(n):
    global factorial
    while n > 1:
        factorial = factorial * n
        factorial_recursive(n - 1)
    return factorial
```

Keep in mind however, using `global` variables is almost always a terrible idea.

Why not just get rid of it altogether and accumulatively multiply?

```py
def factorial_recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial_recursive(n - 1)
```

This is the most common and naive recursive factorial implementation. But it is certainly far better than using global variables.

Comment: Worth noting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/843953

Comment: @PranavHosangadi very much so, indeed.